# Derive expression for charge accumulation from the electric current equation?

Tags: calculus, integration

During my studies, my book gave me an equation to help complete a problem.  With this information I was able to complete the problem with ease.  However, I'm curious because I can't figure out how to derive the equation given to me.

This is an electrical engineering problem but my question regards the math (calculus) behind it, hence I ask this here as opposed to the EE Stack Exchange.

The given equation for electrical current is: $$ i = \frac{dq}{dt} $$

where
$$i = \text{the current in amperes.}$$
$$q = \text{the charge in coulombs.}$$
$$t = \text{the time in seconds}$$

The equation given to me is the expression of charge derived from the equation above:
$$q(t) = \int_0^t i(x)\ dx$$   How do I derive the equation above from the given current equation?

Here is my attempt:

I first integrated the right-hand side with respect to $t$:
$$ \int \frac{dq}{dt}\ dt \implies \int dq\ \implies q(t) $$

I struggle with the left-hand side because I don't get how to integrate with respect to $t$. 
$$\int_0^t i\ dt \text{    ?} $$

How do I express $i$ as a function of $x$ and why has the $dt$ changed to $dx$? Is there a substitution trick that allows me to do this?

I'm sure this is an easy calculus-one question and I appreciate any help in solving this.  Just to reiterate,  this is a math question not an EE question which is why I withheld the EE question details.

Comment: Haven't you derived the integral equation version from the derivative version already?

Comment: @AdrianKeister thank you for the response.  I don't understand the question entirely.   I haven't derived an equation yet.  Both equations were given to me.  The book states the integral equation can be derived from the current equation, i = dq/dt, and I don't know how to do that.

Comment: All you had to do was integrate the RHS just as you did, using the Fundamental Theorem of the Calculus. Then you can switch sides. The limits can be supplied from the FTC as well. The $x$ in the desired equation is just a dummy variable of integration. It doesn't matter what that is.

Comment: @AdrianKeister thank you again.  It's apparent I don't understand the fundamental theorem of calculus.  I thank you for pointing me in the right direction.   Do you have other suggestions for me to research? Will the FTC cover off on the "dummy variable"?

Comment: Can't you just say $ \int\frac{dq}{dt}dt =\int i(t) dt$, or $q(t)=\int i(t) dt$, and then just introduce the bounds? so, assuming your looking at a, for example, time interval $[0,\eta]$, then, for any $\beta \in [0,\eta]$, we can say $q(\beta)-q(0)= \int_0^{\beta} i(t) dt$, where  $\beta$ is say, the time in whatever your units are? Then we can assume $q(0)=0$ if needed? This is assuming everything is Riemann Integrable, of course.